# How to invoke map event in other event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, openlayers, handler

Is there any way to invoke openLayers Map "click" or "pointermove" event in my own event handler?

I'm working on some measurement tool which should make measures on different maps simultaneously. In openLayers map case I'm using drawInteraction to do so. I'm collecting coordinates globally and then putting them in draw.geometryFunction so it works nice.

The problem is that when I'm making measures on container which isn't openLayers Map target, measurement isn't updating on OL container until "dblclick" evt where I'm executing `draw.finishDrawing()` method.

I've tried using `.change()` and `render()` methods on map and draw objects but nothing works for me. Is there any possibility to force map "click" and "pointermove" in my own event handler? Something like jquery .trigger()?

My handler:

```
$(container).on("click.ol", () => {
            if (this.measureHandler.viewerClick === true) {
              this.lastCoord = ol.proj.transform([this.measureHandler.clickCoords[0], this.measureHandler.clickCoords[1]], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857")
            
              if (measureType !== "Polygon") {
                this.coords.push(this.lastCoord)
              } else {
                if (this.coords.length <= 1) {
                  this.coords.splice(0, 0, this.lastCoord)
                  this.coords.push(this.lastCoord)
                } else {
                  this.coords.splice(this.coords.length - 1, 0, this.lastCoord)
                }
              }
              
              // this.clickCount++
              
              // if (this.clickCount === 2 && measureType === "Circle") {
              //   this.clickCount = 0
              //   this.coords = []
              //   this.lastCoord = undefined
              // }
            }
            
          })
```

Mike answer was helpful but `appendCoordinates()` method doesn't work for circle geometries. So if anyone knows the way how to force ol.map "click" and "pointermove" event I would be grateful.

Comment: You could use draw,appendCoordinates to add the coordinates, so no need for clicks.

Comment: Well that kind of does the trick but I also want to do this on mousemove so I've added removeLastPoint() and appendCoordinates() to mousemove handler and because of that when I'm taking back my pointer to the OL map container, the next click I've made ends measurement. If I remove those methods from mousemove handler it works fine, but I need to make it more dynamic.

Comment: Ok it's alive! :D I've just placed `appendCoordinates()` first and then `removeLastPoint()` in mousemove handler. Thanks a lot Mike!

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my question I need to mention that I wanted to use `ol.interaction.Draw`, because it saves a lot of coding with making measurements. That interaction need to be added to `ol.Map` with `.addInteraction()` method and then it works only on element provided when setting up `ol.Map`. So if anyone want to implement similar approach, this is solution for how to do this:

```
this.measureHandler.containers.forEach((container, nr) => {
          $(container).on("click.ol", () => {
            if (this.measureHandler.viewerClick === true) {
              this.lastCoord = ol.proj.transform([this.measureHandler.clickCoords[0], this.measureHandler.clickCoords[1]], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857")
            
              if (measureType !== "Polygon") {
                this.coords.push(this.lastCoord)
              } else {
                if (this.coords.length <= 1) {
                  this.coords.splice(0, 0, this.lastCoord)
                  this.coords.push(this.lastCoord)
                } else {
                  this.coords.splice(this.coords.length - 1, 0, this.lastCoord)
                }
              }

              if (measureType === "Circle") {
                if (this.measureHandler.activePlugins[nr] !== "Ortofoto" && this.measureHandler.activePlugins[nr] !== "Ukosne" && this.measureHandler.activePlugins[nr] !== "OSMPlugin") {
                  if (this.clickCount === 0) {
                    this.draw.appendCoordinates([this.lastCoord])
                    this.clickCount++
                  } else {
                    this.draw.finishDrawing()
                    this.clickCount = 0;
                  }
                }
              } else {
                this.draw.appendCoordinates([this.lastCoord])
                this.clickCount++
              }
            }
          })
  
          $(container).on("mousemove.ol", (evt) => {
            this.maps[nr].removeLayer(this.drawLayer)
            if (nr === 0) {
              this.map2.removeLayer(this.drawLayer)
              this.map2.addLayer(this.drawLayer)
            } else {
              this.map.removeLayer(this.drawLayer)
              this.map.addLayer(this.drawLayer)
            }
            this.maps[nr].addInteraction(this.draw)
            
            this.lastCoord = ol.proj.transform([this.measureHandler.moveCoords[0], this.measureHandler.moveCoords[1]], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857")
  
            if (measureType !== "Polygon") {
              this.coords.pop()
              this.coords.push(this.lastCoord)
            } else {
              if (this.coords.length <= 1) {
                this.coords.pop()
                this.coords.push(this.lastCoord)
              } else {
                this.coords.splice(this.coords.length - 2, 1, this.lastCoord)
              }
            }

            if (nr === 0) {
              olEvt = {
                map: this.map2,
                pixel: this.measureHandler.pixelObj,
                coordinate: this.lastCoord,
                originalEvent: {
                  pointerType: "mouse"
                },
                frameState: this.map2.frameState
              }
            } else {
              olEvt = {
                map: this.map,
                pixel: this.measureHandler.pixelObj,
                coordinate: this.lastCoord,
                originalEvent: {
                  pointerType: "mouse"
                },
                frameState: this.map.frameState
              }
            }
            this.draw.handlePointerMove_(olEvt)
          })
  
          $(container).on("dblclick.ol", () => {
            this.draw.removeLastPoint()
            this.draw.finishDrawing()
            this.clickCount = 0;
          })
        })
```

As you can see I didn't find any way to force "click" event on `ol.Map` but `appendCoordinates()` works well besides "circle" geometry case. To handle "circle" geometry I've added some logic to my `clickHandler` and after that everything works on both containers. On the other hand I've managed to simulate `ol.Map` "pointermove" event in my `mouseMoveHandler`. I've found that `ol.interaction.Draw` have `.handlePointerMove_()` method but you have to provide `ol.MapBrowserEvent` to it so I'm creating object which have every data that `.handlePointerMove_()` method wants from me and my problem is solved.